# Projection of images in fisherspace(LDA)

Tags: c++, opencv, lda

In Linear Discriminant Analysis algorithm for face recognition, the between class scatter matrix and within class scatter matrix are both of size MxM (M=total number of images, C=number of classes). The fisherspace(matrix with eigenvectors as columns) consists of the eigenvectors corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues and hence has dimension Mx(C-1). How am I supposed to project the training phase images, each in N-dimensional space, onto the fisherspace.(Correct me if I am wrong). Can anybody help me figure this out?

> http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5256630

This is the research paper I followed to implement LDA. I am trying to implement it in OpenCV using C++

Comment: Why would you [redo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/src/fisher_faces.cpp) the [wheel](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/modules/core/src/lda.cpp)?

Comment: I am a beginner and need to do step-wise implementation for a project with my own understanding

Comment: Looking at OpenCV's implementation cannot hurt. That particular portion is especially well-written, and the projection is [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/modules/core/src/lda.cpp#L171). It amounts to subtracting the mean from the image, and matrix-multiplying by the matrix of eigenvectors.